# How to disable a button until all entries that are dynamically generated or in a datagrid are filled

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a form that has fields that are dynamically generated, I want to disable the button that needs to be clicked after all entries are filled.
I'm using the MVVM architecture. And also my button is using the AddScoreCommand.

```
    public SubmitDataViewModel()
    {
        AddScoreCommand = new Command(CmdSubData);

    }



    private async void CmdSubData()
    {
      //Scorelist contains data that is displayed in the form that needs 
       //to be submitted
        foreach (var element in Scorelist)
            {

            var _scoreDef = new scores
            {
                ID = element.ID,
                SCORES = element.SCORES, //Gets entered value from entry
                GOAL_ID = element.ID,


            };

           response = await apiServices.SubmitScore(_scoreDef); 

            }


    }
```

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: Yes I solved the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use data-binding to bind the property **isEnable** of Button in your ViewModel .

#### in xaml

```
<Button Command="{Binding AddScoreCommand}" IsEnabled="{Binding isEnable}"/>
```

#### in ViewModel

```
public class SubmitDataViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public ICommand AddScoreCommand { get; set; }


    private bool isenable;

    public bool isEnable
    {
        get
        {
            return isenable;
        }

        set
        {
            if (isenable != value)
            {
                isenable = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

    }


    public SubmitDataViewModel()
    {
        //...

        isEnable = true; // set the default value
    }

    private async void CmdSubData()
    {
        //Scorelist contains data that is displayed in the form that needs 
        //to be submitted
        foreach (var element in Scorelist)
        {

            var _scoreDef = new scores
            {
                ID = element.ID,
                SCORES = element.SCORES, //Gets entered value from entry
                GOAL_ID = element.ID,


            };

            response = await apiServices.SubmitScore(_scoreDef);

        }

        isEnable = false; // change the value after submit 
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do it via jquery validation plugin. (https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

In the submit controller you also need to check if all the fields are not null to prevent problem if the user manipulate the dom. (the user can easly enable the button via the developer's tool)